# Visual Studio transferência de controle desvia a inicialização de:

Tags: c++, c++11

```
switch (option) {
case 1:
    int var;
    std::vector<int>v(size);
    std::list<int>l;

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (vector): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (list): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> var;
        l.push_front(var);
    }

    bubbleSort(v);
    bubbleSort(l);

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto x : l) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    break;
case 2:
    double var;
    std::vector<double>v(size);
    std::list<double>l;

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (vector): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (list): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> var;
        l.push_front(var);
    }

    bubbleSort(v);
    bubbleSort(l);

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto x : l) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    break;
case 3:
    char var;
    std::vector<char>v(size);
    std::list<char>l;

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (vector): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> v[i];
    }

    std::cout << "Digite os elementos do container (list): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cin >> var;
        l.push_front(var);
    }

    bubbleSort(v);
    bubbleSort(l);

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (auto x : l) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    break;
}
```

Por que estou recebendo essa mensagem ? O que seria isso?

Erro (ativo)    E0546   transferência de controle desvia a inicialização de:
            variável "v" (declarado na linha 29)
            variável "l" (declarado na linha 30)
            variável "v" (declarado na linha 58)
            variável "l" (declarado na linha 59)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque chaves em cada "case":

```
switch (option) {
  case 1:
  {
    int var;
    std::vector<int>v(size);
    std::list<int>l;
    //...
    //...
    break;
  }

  case 2:
  {
    double var;
    std::vector<double>v(size);
    std::list<double>l;
    //...
    //...
    break;
  }

  case 3:
  {
    char var;
    std::vector<char>v(size);
    std::list<char>l;
    //...
    //...
    break;
  }

} // switch
```

Por que estou recebendo essa mensagem ? O que seria isso?

Comment: O problema foi resolvido brigado pela ajuda! :D